# JQuery Datatables : Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I created this fiddle to and it works well as per my requirements: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swateekj/ekm342n5/1/)

However, when I use the same in my application I get an error in the browser console saying **Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined**

In my application, the javascript reads something like as below: I have checked the controller output...it works well and is printed on the console too.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.getJSON("three.htm", function(data) {
             // console.log("loadDataTable >>  "+JSON.stringify(data));
             })
             .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
             var err = textStatus + ', ' + error;
             alert(err);
             console.log( "Request Failed: " + err);
             })
             .success(function(data){
                 loadDataTable(data);
             });

    function loadDataTable(data){
         $("#recentSubscribers").dataTable().fnDestroy();    
         var oTable = $('#recentSubscribers').dataTable({
             "aaData" : JSON.parse(data.subscribers),
             "processing": true,
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bFilter": false,
            "bSort": false,
            "bInfo": false,
            "aoColumnDefs": [{
            "sTitle": "Subscriber ID",
            "aTargets": [0]
        }, {
            "sTitle": "Install Location",
            "aTargets": [1]
        }, {
            "sTitle": "Subscriber Name",
            "aTargets": [2]
        }, {
            "aTargets": [0], 
            "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                return '<a style="text-decoration:none;" href="#" class="abc">' + data + '</a>';
            }
        }],
            "aoColumns": [{
            "mData": "code"
        }, {
            "mData": "acctNum"
        }, {
            "mData": "name"
        }]
            });

    }       

})
```

Comment: Please be sure that the code you included it's the same as the fiddle (it's not) and the one that you are running. Also in the fiddle you have two aTargets[0], check: http://jsfiddle.net/gL0p0t42/

Comment: You are not providing the source that actually call "aDataSort".

Comment: Do you mean the id of the html table? I have taken care of that. Let me try with having one target.

Comment: @Daniel the source is the parameter to the loadDataTable() function.

Comment: @PatrickLC this isn't working what you suggested. I put the aTargets[0] in one place..but the error still persists.

Comment: [related (newer) question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30348028/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-adatasort-of-undefined) with answer

Comment: I had the same problem , and i find that i order by a column number which is not exist..  i had only 3 cols but i ordered by the fifth .

Answer (score 169):

It's important that your THEAD not be empty in table.As dataTable requires you to specify the number of columns of the expected data .
As per your data it should be

```html
<table id="datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Subscriber ID</th>
            <th>Install Location</th>
            <th>Subscriber Name</th>
            <th>some data</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: What if I have a requirement that involves configuring columns and the number of said columns at Runtime?  How can I implement code for the aforementioned requirement?

Comment: This helped me to cure my problem of data not printed. Well it also helped me to cure one more problem of mine for datatable where i wrote `"Sort":false`, then it was able to view the list in descending order that came from controller as `Model.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Action==0).ThenBy(x=>x.Action)`.

Comment: the `<thead>` must contain a `<tr>` , then `<th>`s

Comment: This is true for a standard DataTable (and solve my issue). RE: @CSLewis : I'm not sure with static tables, but if you are configuring columns at runtime alongside an ajax request it is not required to have anything in `<thead>` but you must define the columns in your DataTable() initiation like this: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data

Answer (score 93):

Also had this issue,
This array was out of range:

```
order: [1, 'asc'],
```

Comment: This one always gets me. Is there a way to default the array to 0, if the array is out of range?

Comment: @JGreasley You can set it as an empty array: order: []

Comment: Mine columns where 5 and i was specifying 7 here !
Thanks

Comment: One! Week! One full week! And that's a 7-day week! And I'm pretty sure that I was _not_ working 9-to-5, more like 9-to-midnight... all of that lost _because I didn't know about this bug_!! Arrrrrrrrrrrgh!! ... So much time wasted, I feel deeply ashamed, I searched the Internet over and over again and experimented with all possible solutions — none would come even close to 'fix' this. And then... by mere chance and already despairing... I came across your answer, and ta-da! In five minutes, _everything was fixed_.
If I were rich, I'd send you a cheque for €10K — lol

Answer (score 15):

For me, the bug was in DataTables itself; The code for sorting in DataTables 1.10.9 will not check for bounds; thus if you use something like

```
order: [[1, 'asc']]
```

with an empty table, there is no row idx 1 -> this exception ensures.
This happened as the data for the table was being fetched asynchronously. Initially, on page loading the dataTable gets initialized without data. It should be updated later as soon as the result data is fetched.

My solution:

```
// add within function _fnStringToCss( s ) in datatables.js
// directly after this line
// srcCol = nestedSort[i][0];

if(srcCol >= aoColumns.length) {
    continue;
}

// this line follows:
// aDataSort = aoColumns[ srcCol ].aDataSort;
```

Comment: Thank you for your elaboration on this issue; @hogarth45 [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44137826/1035977) identified the problem/bug correctly, but was not so clear about _why_ this was, in fact, _a_ problem. I'm answering you two years later... and apparently this hasn't been corrected, not even mentioned in the official documentation, at least, as far as I know.

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same problem, the following changes solved my problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.datatable').dataTable( {
            bSort: false,
            aoColumns: [ { sWidth: "45%" }, { sWidth: "45%" }, { sWidth: "10%", bSearchable: false, bSortable: false } ],
        "scrollY":        "200px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "info":           true,
        "paging":         true
    } );
} );
```

the `aoColumns` array describes the width of each column and its `sortable` properties.

> Another thing to mention this error will also appear when you order by a column
>   number that does not exist.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I had

```
$(`#my_table`).empty();
```

Where it should have been

```
$(`#my_table tbody`).empty();
```

Note: in my case I had to empty the table since i had data that I wanted gone before inserting new data.

Just thought of sharing where it "might" help someone in the future!

Answer (score 4):

In my case I solved the problem by establishing a valid column number when applying the `order` property inside the script where you configure the data table.

```
var table = $('#mytable').DataTable({
     .
     .
     .
     order: [[ 1, "desc" ]],
```

Comment: There are already other answers saying basically the same thing. Please try to avoid redundant answers on questions that are years-old.

Answer (score 3):

You need to switch single quotes `[']` to double quotes `["]` because of parse

if you are using **data-order** attribute on the table then use it like this `data-order='[[1, "asc"]]'`

Comment: it's not relevant with the OP's question but it works on my case (using html 5 data attributes)

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time it occurs when something is undefined. I copied the code and removed few columns which disturbed the order by index. Carefully make changes and every variable after it.
"order": [[1, "desc"]], fixed my issues previous i was using "order": [[24, "desc"]], and that index was not avaialble.

Answer (score 3):

**My Solution**

add this :

```
order: 1 ,
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and it was because another script was deleting all of the tables and recreating them, but my table wasn't being recreated. I spent ages on this issue before I noticed that my table wasn't even visible on the page.  Can you see your table before you initialize DataTables?

Essentially, the other script was doing:

```
let tables = $("table");
for (let i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
  const table = tables[i];
  if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable(table)) {
    $(table).DataTable().destroy(remove);
    $(table).empty();
  }
}
```

And it should have been doing:

```
let tables = $("table.some-class-only");
... the rest ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the error by having multiple tables on the page and trying to initialize them all at once like this:

```
$('table').DataTable();
```

After a lot of trial and error, I initialized them separately and the error went away:

```
$("#table1-id").DataTable();
$("#table2-id").DataTable();
```

Comment: For me I commented out the code to generate a hidden table column which had another table embedded in it and ran it - I am still getting that error.  I upgraded JQuery and JQuery UI to latest versions and I still get this problem. My code did NOT have jquery code to run DataTable on it - I was going to display it as a child table but not as a DataTable, that is why I never called .DataTable() on it.

Answer (score 2):

Just my two cents regarding `order: [...]`;
It won't check items type, and in my case I was passing `[arrOrders]` as opposed to just `arrOrders` or `[...arrOrders]`, resulting in `[[[ 1, "desc" ], [ 2, "desc" ]]]`.

Answer (score 1):

For me
adding columns in this format

```
columns: [
    { data: 'name' },
    { data: 'position' },
    { data: 'salary' },
    { data: 'state_date' },
    { data: 'office' },
    { data: 'extn' }
]
```

and ajax at this format

```
 ajax: {
  url: '/api/foo',
  dataSrc: ''
},
```

solved for me  .

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but in my case I was passing an unrelated order= in the URL that would sometimes be empty.  Once I changed the url variable to "sortorder" or anything other than "order" the plugin began working normally.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, In my case one of the columns was not receiving proper data. some of the columns had strings in place of Integers. after i fixed it it started working properly. In most of the cases the issue is "table not receiveing proper data".

Answer (score 0):

I was getting from DataTables.min.js this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')" when I did (modified from what I did):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var table = $('#MySelector').DataTable({
                columnDefs: [{ target: 0, width: "55%", type: "string", className: "dt-left" },
                             { target: 1, width: "10%", type: "datetime-moment", className: "dt-left" },
                             { target: 2, width: "10%", type: 
                             { target: 3, width: "0", className: "dt-left", visible: false } ],
                order: [[0, 'asc']], autoWidth: false, bFilter: true, scrollCollapse: false, paging: false, bInfo: true, ordering: true 
                /*,stateSave: false*/
            });

           table.rows().every(function (e) { });
}
```

But for me the problem got fixed when I instead did this:

```
table.rows().every(function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {

});
```

Now according to DataTables.net both are supposed to be valid - but only the second example for me doesn't blow up:
https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().every()