# jQuery TableSorter Plugin(Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined)

Tags: jquery, pagination, tablesorter

i am using this plugin for pagination .[this](https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter)

i includes files in my header as follow:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('_assets/js/jQuery-2.1.3.min.js');?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('_assets/js/tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js');?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('_assets/js/tablesorter/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js');?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

my page script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#p_history")
    .tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']})
    .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")});
});
```

> Error :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined

Does anyone know the solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As i am seeing, you are using `2.0` jquery version, and probably tablesorter plugin working with old jquery version..

Error is occuring because `$.browser.mise` function has deprecated in jQuery 2.0 version, so you should use older jQuery version <= 1.3.
Or use compatible sorter plunin.

Comment: i can't used old version because i need latest jquery version.

Comment: you may resolve the `$.browser` using custom plugin code, but there other functions might also be deprecated,  so better to use supported jQuery or other table sorter plugin, i would recommend  [Data Table](https://www.datatables.net/) , it will work with new jQuery 2.0 version

Comment: how data table plugin works ,there is no documentaion on their website can you please explain please.

Comment: many examples on site https://www.datatables.net/examples/index   https://datatables.net/docs/DataTables/1.9.4/

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454203/jquery-datatables-cannot-read-property-adatasort-of-undefined

Comment: Another option is to try my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), there are only a [few changes in the original options](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/wiki/Summary) plus many more options, widgets & parsers.