# Datatables doesn't work on empty table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

```
<table></table>

<script>

$(function () {
    $('table').each(function () {
        $(this).DataTable(
               {

                   stateSave: true,
                   "sDom": 'C<"clear">rfrtip',
                   "scrollCollapse": true,
                   "paging": true,
                   responsive: true
            });

    });

});
```

**Occurring error:**

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined<br/>
         at _fnSortFlatten (jquery.dataTables.js:5889)<br/>
         at _fnSortingClasses (jquery.dataTables.js:6227)<br/>
         at loadedInit (jquery.dataTables.js:1234)<br/>
         at loaded (jquery.dataTables.js:6341)<br/>
         at _fnLoadState (jquery.dataTables.js:6425)<br/>
         at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.js:1329)<br/>
         at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)<br/>
         at w.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)<br/>
         at w.fn.init.DataTable [as dataTable] (jquery.dataTables.js:869)<br/>
         at w.fn.init.$.fn.DataTable (jquery.dataTables.js:15172)
```

I also tried

```
<table><thead></thead><tbody></tbody></table>
```

EDIT :
How to fix this **without filling thead**?

Comment: May be this answer is your solution, https://stackoverflow.com/a/32476369/1578380

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery Datatables : Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454203/jquery-datatables-cannot-read-property-adatasort-of-undefined)

Comment: DataTables 1.10.9 will not check for bounds. Oliver's suggestion fixes this bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454203/jquery-datatables-cannot-read-property-adatasort-of-undefined/32476369#49822492