# Javascript Datatable dynamic data

Tags: javascript, datatable

I used dataTable.min.js javascript file in my project. I filled data for table as dynamic. But I have giving an error. Can you help me.

Error Detail: jquery.dataTables.min.js:65 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined

Comment: Please show your code what you have tried till.

Comment: var dataSet = [
  ["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800"],
     ["Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675"]
];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datatable').DataTable({       
        data:  dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "Position" },
            { title: "Office" },
            { title: "Extn." },
            { title: "Start date" },
            { title: "Salary" }
        ]
    });
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like the data being returned is empty and hence it can not read property of undefined, anyways post code to analyze more or you can see if you find any answer here
 ->[JQuery Datatables : Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454203/jquery-datatables-cannot-read-property-adatasort-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

i had assigned tables id as name "datatable". and then i thought , it will be problem. and then i changed the id as "example". it that works