# add checkbox to datatable jquery

Tags: jquery

[image]I am unable to add checkbox inside the table ,I tried lot of things but everything went to vain

Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var total = [];
  $.ajax({
    url: 'user.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
      // get the `airport` array 
      var device = json.siteList;
      var j = 1;

      // loop through the array to populate your list
      $.each(device, function(i, sites) {
        // console.log(sites.siteName)
        // $('#data_table').append("<tr>" + "<td>" + sites.siteName + "</td>" + "</tr>");
        $.each(sites.deviceList, function(i, values) {

          item = {}
          item['siteName'] = sites.siteName;
          item["deviceName"] = values.deviceName;
          item["count"] = values.count;
          total.push(item);

        });
      });

      $('#rpa_table').DataTable(
        columnDefs: [{
          orderable: false,
          className: 'select-checkbox',
          targets: 0
        }],
        select: {
          style: 'os',
          selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        order: [
          [1, 'asc']
        ], {
          "aaData": total,
          "aoColumns": [{
              "sTitle": "Site",
              "mData": "siteName"
            },
            {
              "sTitle": "Cabinet",
              "mData": "deviceName"
            },
            {
              "sTitle": "Count",
              "mData": "count"
            },
          ],

        });

    }
  });
  // Handle click on "Select all" control
  // Handle click on "Select all" control
  $('#checkall').on('click', function() {
    // Check/uncheck all checkboxes in the table
    var rows = table.rows({
      'search': 'applied'
    }).nodes();
    $('input[type="checkbox"]', rows).prop('checked', this.checked);
  });

});
```

Every Time I add columnDef it shows me an error[image]

The image is attached above,
checked a lot of sites no clue nothing same error occures everytime
any help would be highly appreciated
Thanks in advance....................

Comment: Presumably, you should be passing an object to the DataTable constructor. Objects are enclosed in `{}`. eg `$('#rpa_table').DataTable({ columnDefs: [] })`

Comment: ypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined this error is coming

Comment: [Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454203/jquery-datatables-cannot-read-property-adatasort-of-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some syntax errors around your options being passed into `.DataTables()`. See my comments below:

```
$('#rpa_table').DataTable({     // <-- Need a curly brace here
    columnDefs: [ 
        {
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets:   0
        }
    ],
    select: {
        style: 'os',
        selector: 'td:first-child'
    },
    order: [
        [ 1, 'asc' ]
    ],
    {
        "aaData": total,
        "aoColumns": [
            {
                "sTitle": "Site",
                "mData": "siteName"
            },
            {
                "sTitle": "Cabinet",
                "mData": "deviceName"
            },
            {
                "sTitle": "Count",
                "mData": "count"
            }     // <-- Remove the trailing comma here
        ]         // <-- Remove the trailing comma here
    }             // <-- Close the inner object here
});               // <-- Close the options object here
```

When passing options to `.DataTables()` you have to pass the contents as an *options* object. This includes the opening and closing curly braces at the opening parathensis and the closing parathensis.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{',this error is coming

Comment: @Swarnadeep Can you post an edit with an updated screenshot to your question please? I'm not sure what line that would be occuring at.

Comment: @War10ck: The curly brace after `order` attribute is not necessary, neither it's closing brace.