# Angular reactive forms checkbox validations

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to make a required validation to my checkboxes.

My TS file :

```js
public colors: Array<any> = [
     { description: 'White', value: 'White' },
     { description: 'Black', value: 'Black' },
     { description: 'Blue', value: 'Blue' },
     { description: 'Green', value: 'Green' },
     { description: 'Yellow', value: 'Yellow' },
     { description: 'Red', value: 'Red' },
];
    
constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private heroService: HeroService,
    private toastr: ToastrService
  ) {
  this.fromInit();
}

ngOnInit(): void {}

fromInit() {
  this.heroCreateForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    suitColors: new FormArray([], [Validators.required]),
  });
}

onCheckChange(event) {
  const formArray: FormArray = this.heroCreateForm.get(
    'suitColors'
  ) as FormArray;

  if (event.target.checked) {
    formArray.push(new FormControl(event.target.value));
  } else {
    let i: number = 0;

    formArray.controls.forEach((ctrl: FormControl) => {
      if (ctrl.value == event.target.value) {
        formArray.removeAt(i);
        return;
      }
      i++;
    });
  }
}


invalidSuitColorsMessage() {
   // this function doesn't work
   if (this.suitColors.errors?.required)
      return "You must choose the hero's suit colors";
}
```

My HTML file :

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <form [formGroup]="heroCreateForm" (ngSubmit)="createHero()">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="input-container-suitColors-input">
        <label><b>Suit colors: </b></label>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let color of colors; let i=index">
          <div class="radio-contatiner">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   [value]="color.value"
                   (change)="onCheckChange($event)">
            {{color.description}}
          </div>
        </ng-container>
      </div>

      <div class="invalid-input-message"
           *ngIf="suitColors.touched && suitColors.invalid">{{invalidSuitColorsMessage()}}</div>

// here is the issue. I'm getting here an error

      <hr>

      <button type="submit"
              class="registerbtn"
              [disabled]="heroCreateForm.invalid">Register</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Error**

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'touched')

I do understand why it does work. I search online and didn't find any solution to my issue.

I'm trying to show a message if the required error happens on those checkboxes

Does anyone can take a look and explain to me why does it happen and how should I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting an undefined object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Comment: The object `suitColors` is undefined, you should check at this. Lot of information about the undefined error are on multiple SO question like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32317154/10952503), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28454203/10952503)

Comment: Hi i didn't really find any way to fix it from those articles 
How would you make the validation ?

Comment: Let me make an answer to explain how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

The error said the variable `touched` can't be found because the object that should contains it is not defined. In other language it's also called as `null`. [More explaination about undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27509)

In your case, `suitColors` is not defined. So there is multiple ways :

1. You can define it. For example, in the constructor like that:

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private heroService: HeroService,
   private toastr: ToastrService, public suitColors: MyObject) {
   this.fromInit();
}
```

Or as public variable like that :

```
public suitColors: MyObject;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private heroService: HeroService, private toastr: ToastrService) {
   this.suitColors = new MyObject();
   this.fromInit();
}
```

2. Check in the `*ngIf` before use it. With this way, you should add a check for ALL object. Also, this will work everytime, even if you define object after ngInit.

```html
<div class="invalid-input-message"
           *ngIf="suitColors != null && suitColors.touched && suitColors.invalid"> 
    {{invalidSuitColorsMessage()}}
</div>
```